# Jquery modify url of all requests

Tags: javascript, jquery

For $.get and $.post I want to transform the url to 'http://www.corsproxy.com/' + url.replace("https://", "") How do I overwrite get and post to do this?

With this example:

```
$.get('http://blockchain.info/address/1HbUnKwQVYmyao1aMpWHVCGrpuTndTeuec?format=json', function(data) {
    WS.log(data.final_balance);
});
```

I want $.get to change http://blockchain.info/address/1HbUnKwQVYmyao1aMpWHVCGrpuTndTeuec?format=json to http://www.corsproxy.com/blockchain.info/address/1HbUnKwQVYmyao1aMpWHVCGrpuTndTeuec?format=json

Comment: Can't quite get your question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can accomplish thing by overriding the `$.get` & `$.post` methods as follows:

```
var oPost = jQuery.post;
jQuery.post = function() {
    arguments[0] =  'http://www.corsproxy.com/' + arguments[0].replace("http://", "").replace("https://", "");
    return oPost.apply(this, arguments);
};

$.post('http://www.google.co.in', function(d){ /* take action */});
```

Comment: @downvoter Reason for down-voting please?

Answer (score -1):

?? Strange requirement. Anyway:

For replacing the url:

```
url.replace("http://", "http://www.corsproxy.com/");
```

if you wrap it in a function:

```
function corsify(url){
   return url.replace("http://", "http://www.corsproxy.com/");
}
```

So instead of this:

```
$.get(url, ...);
```

you would do:

```
$.get(corsify(url), ...);
```

I would **not** recommend to override the `$.get` or `$.post` methods.

Cheers

Comment: He wishes to ensure that all calls made using `$.get` & `$.post` methods go to `'http://www.corsproxy.com/'+ <url_without_http_https>` and he does not wish to do this manually for each URL. Also, he is aware of the `.replace` method of JavaScript